# Build valgrind for Android failed with error "ld: error: unable to find library -lgcc"

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling, valgrind

The official website of valgrind says that it supports arm32-Android. I tried to compile valgrind with NDK, but got the error that libgcc could not be found.

My NDK version & target:

```
android-ndk-r23
Target Android ABI: armeabi-v7a
Target Android API: 28
```

My build script:

```sh
# define vars：
export TOOLCHAIN="${NDK_DIR}/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64"
export TARGET="armv7a-linux-androideabi"
export API=28
export AR="${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/llvm-ar"
export CC="${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/${TARGET}${API}-clang"
export AS="${CC}"
export CXX="${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/${TARGET}${API}-clang++"
export LD="${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/ld"
export RANLIB="${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/llvm-ranlib"
export STRIP="${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/llvm-strip"

# gen configure file：
cd ${SRC_DIR}
bash autogen.sh || exit 1

# Configure gen makefile：
cd ${BUILD_DIR} && rm -rf ./*
${SRC_DIR}/configure \
    --host=${TARGET} \
    --target=${TARGET} \
    --prefix="${BUILD_DIR}/../install_ndk" || exit 1

make -j8
```

But got error:

```sh
../coregrind/link_tool_exe_linux 0x58000000 /home/hao/app_NDK/android-ndk-r23/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi28-clang     -o memcheck-arm-linux  -m32 -O2 -g -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wempty-body -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wignored-qualifiers -Wenum-conversion -finline-functions -fno-stack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-builtin -Wno-cast-align -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -marm -mcpu=cortex-a8 -O2 -static -nodefaultlibs -nostartfiles -u _start -Wl,--build-id=none -m32 -Wl,-z,noexecstack memcheck_arm_linux-mc_leakcheck.o memcheck_arm_linux-mc_malloc_wrappers.o memcheck_arm_linux-mc_main.o memcheck_arm_linux-mc_main_asm.o memcheck_arm_linux-mc_translate.o memcheck_arm_linux-mc_machine.o memcheck_arm_linux-mc_errors.o ../coregrind/libcoregrind-arm-linux.a ../VEX/libvex-arm-linux.a -lgcc ../coregrind/libgcc-sup-arm-linux.a 
ld: error: unable to find library -lgcc
clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```